# jQuery isotope: Infinite Scroll and filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I have a grid of products set up with the isotope plugin, the products are paginated and loaded in on the scroll with the infinite scroll plugin. This works fine, but as there are so many products we've also added a number of filters, again this filters work great but when combined with the infinite scroll I run into some problems, as when I initiate the filter, if the results aren't on the first page, you then have to wait for all the pages to load before any results are shown. 
So my question is, is there a more sophisticated way of combining both the isotope filtering and infinite scroll? My markup is as follows:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var $container = $('.products-grid-wrap');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.products-grid-block',
            filter: '*:not(.hidden), .products-grid-block',
            animationEngine: 'best-available',
            layoutMode: "perfectMasonry",
            perfectMasonry: {
              columnWidth: 280,
              rowHeight: 310
            }
        });

        $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: '#page_nav', // selector for the paged navigation 
            nextSelector: '#page_nav a', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
            itemSelector: '.regular-product-block, .products-grid-block', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
            pixelsFromNavToBottom: Math.round($(window).height() * 2.5),
            bufferPx: Math.round($(window).height() * 2.5),
            loading: {
                finishedMsg: 'No more products to load.',
                img: 'URL/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/ajax-loader-big.gif'
            }
        },
        // call Isotope as a callback
        function (newElements) {
            var $newElems = $(newElements);
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
                $container.isotope('insert', $newElems);
                $('.products-grid-rollover-block').hide();                 
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.products-grid-wrap').isotope('reLayout');
                    //$('.products-grid-wrap').isotope({
                    //sortBy: 'category',
                        //sortAscending: false });
                }, 500);
            });
        });            

    });

    $('.products-header-category-select, #products-filter-all-categories').click(function () {
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/1358 by creator of Isotope: "Infinite Scroll with Isotope's filtering and sorting is not a good user experience."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your filter click function within function (newElements).
Try this:

```
$(window).load(function () {

var $container = $('.products-grid-wrap');

$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.products-grid-block',
        filter: '*:not(.hidden), .products-grid-block',
        animationEngine: 'best-available',
        layoutMode: "perfectMasonry",
        perfectMasonry: {
          columnWidth: 280,
          rowHeight: 310
        }
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: '#page_nav', // selector for the paged navigation 
        nextSelector: '#page_nav a', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector: '.regular-product-block, .products-grid-block', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        pixelsFromNavToBottom: Math.round($(window).height() * 2.5),
        bufferPx: Math.round($(window).height() * 2.5),
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'No more products to load.',
            img: 'URL/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/ajax-loader-big.gif'
        }
    },
    // call Isotope as a callback
    function (newElements) {
        var $newElems = $(newElements);
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.isotope('insert', $newElems);
            $('.products-grid-rollover-block').hide();                 
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.products-grid-wrap').isotope('reLayout');
                //$('.products-grid-wrap').isotope({
                //sortBy: 'category',
                    //sortAscending: false });
            }, 500);
        });
    $('.products-header-category-select, #products-filter-all-categories').click(function () {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });

    return false;
}); 
    });            

});   
});
```

Comment: this hasn't really improved the problem. The filtering was and is working (to a degree), but if the filter results aren't on pages already loaded, then when you initiate a filter, you're greeted with an empty screen until the rest of the pages have loaded in and the relevant blocks are available to filter. If that makes sense?

Comment: I see, I thought the filter was not working after infinite scroll. You want to filter items not already loaded on the page?

Comment: yes it does work, but obviously as some pages haven't loaded yet, it filters all items out until the relevant page has loaded. So yes, essentially I want to filter items that haven't loaded on the page yet and then load the relevant elements into the page.

Comment: Not sure how you can filter items not yet loaded in the DOM but maybe someone does. Your best bet is to try and filter as they load by including the filter you want in the callback on isotope in infinitescroll, so it filters as they load.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently MixItUp (free non-commercially) [using the Dataset API](https://www.kunkalabs.com/tutorials/using-the-dataset-api/) with the [Pagination extension ($25)](https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup-pagination/) could do this.

Also see: https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup/

Latest update to the repo as of this writing was Oct. 1 2018 and there a quite some open issues in the GitHub repo. Sadly seems not very well maintained.